# Difference between ./ and / when accessing root on HTML

Tags: html

I see the HTML code for getting to the root of a website using just / and sometimes using ./

Which one is the best practice, since they appear to achieve the same objective of navigating to the root, when dealing with root files?

ex: if I'm on an index.html file in the root directory, is there any best practice difference between using / or ./ for other pages that are on root? Or is it irrelevant for the browsers which way I point it?

Comment: Edited: I might have wrongly phrased the question. I'm assuming I'm working on a document that it's on the root and linking to others on the root. (it used to say any folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally stick to the root relative path: `/` or scheme relative path: `//`. If you move the page you don't need to remember to change the paths.

The scheme relative path will take the http/https of the current page.

Answer (score 2):

`/` and `./` are two completely different commands, resulting in different paths.

`/` is an absolute path, which will take you to the root directory of the user, whilst `./` is a relative path, which takes you to the current directory you're on.

You can only get to the root of the website (for example, the public folder) with `./` if you are literally in that folder.

Comment: But if I'm on an index.html file in the root directory, is there any best practice difference between using / or ./ for other pages that are on root? Or is it irrelevant for the browsers which way I point it?

Comment: `/` is **not** an absolute path, it is a root relative URL

Comment: I mean / is an absolute path in context to the usage of slash. For example, /etc/ is an absolute path, where as ./etc/ is a relative path to a folder called "etc" in your current path

Comment: @migueltomarnogueira 

If you are already in the same folder that contains index.html, just use ./ the whole point of ./ is to reference your current directory

Comment: Thanks @alex067 I was wondering if it made any difference for browsers or web servers since I watch both pratices

Comment: @alex067 , **not** in a web context. While the syntax is similar to paths in the command line the meaning is quite different when it comes to `/`.  In a web context "https://something.com/path/" is an absolute path/url

Comment: @JonP So if you're refering to root files inside root files on a web context, it's best to have a safer ./ relative path, even if they are on the root?

Comment: Apologies!  After reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL), Mozilla now considers root relative paths to be absolute.

Comment: @migueltomarnogueira , no stick with `/` it will always map to the same location, regardless of the location of the file.

Comment: Thanks! Solved! @JonP

Comment: @JonP Doesn't this entirely depend on the web server, and what OS its running under? Generally speaking, in Windows & Linux, ./ is a relative path while / is an absolute path.

Comment: It *shouldn't* , the U in URL is "Uniform" after all. In a flat html / css or javascript a URL should behave the same, regardless of the server. I would go as far to say that I've seen `./` only very rarely in production code in nearly 20 years of web dev. `../` , `/` and `something/` much more often.